# ImageMagick command to strip ICC color profiles

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I have ~500 images that all seem to have a color profile on them; as when I upload to Shopify it changes the color tone of the images. This is due to Shopify stripping out the color profile on upload as per this link:

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/colors-images-and-video/fix-colors-of-uploaded-images

I have tried to use ImageMagick to strip out all the color profiles: `mogrify +profile "-strip" *.jpg` and this noticeably changes the image color which I can see on the image thumbnail but when I try uploading to Shopify the color is still being changed.

What am I doing wrong with ImageMagick? Or maybe it's not a color profile that needs removing?

I have also tried this on Photoshop using 'Save for Web', and this method strips out the color profile, but I don't want to do this for ~500 images, and File > Automate > Batch in CS6 doesn't have any Action for Save For Web. Can this be automated? I am running Windows.

Thanks

- Original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P6mx.jpg
- Shopify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkqxK.jpg
- Photoshop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esSGp.jpg

EDIT:
I have run ImageMagick `identity` on the image 3 times. On the original image, on the image after upload to Shopify, and then 'save image as' and again after doing save for web on Photoshop 
http://pastebin.com/710fHhJ0

Observations:

- Original image: CMYK, ColorSeparation
- Shopify image: sRGB, TrueColor
- Photoshop image: sRGB, TrueColor

Comment: Maybe share some images...

Comment: I do not see how stripping your colour profile before upload is going to help as Shopify will remove it anyway. The way I see it is you need to fix the original images without a colour profile. You can check your image information in Imagemagick with identify -verbose image.jpg You need to check the before upload and Shopify images to see what has changed.

Comment: Hi, sorry i got called away. I have run `identity` on the image 3 times. on the original image, on the image after uplaod from shopify, and then 'save image as' and again after doing `save for web` on Photoshop
pastebin.com/710fHhJ0

Comment: If the difference is the colourspace, you can change it with **ImageMagick** with `convert input.jpg -strip -colorspace sRGB result.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell nope, that just turns it into the same incorrect color as uploading to Shopify. I have found an answer now, but it doesn't use ImageMagick :(

Comment: @PShaw: Please can you upload a sample image.

Answer (score 0):

So after another ~hour of playing around I looked into Photoshop Automation. Turns out you can record your own macro and play it back. I wasn't aware you could record your own hence trying to play around with ImageMagick and this question.

For those who may stumble across this:

- Window > Actions
- [pops up on the toolbar]
- Click the folded paper (New Action)
- The record (circle) should now change to Red, it is recording.
- Carry out your action, e.g mine was to go to File>Save for Web>click OK
- Once finished your repetitive task, click the Stop button (square)
- Now use your new recorded action, File > Automate > Batch

Unfortunately, this doesn't help those trying to do Save For Web using ImageMagick only.